# How to detect the different layers in an Image

Tags: c#, javascript, html, wpf

I am working on an application in WPF C# , in which I Have an image where I want to detect the different Layers of Image , so that i can change the color of layers by choosing any color from color pallet (which is either normal color OR gradient color).
[image]

Suppose I have above Image , In the Image there are different layers like (wall , sofa , tiles , window , pillow etc.) . Nowe my question is how to detect the **wall layer** of Image & change it's color from **yellow gradient to something else which is either normal color Or gradient color** , Same for other layers of image like **sofa** , detect the **sofa & change it's color from white to something else** & same with window , floor , pillow layers of Image .

Comment: (wall , sofa , tiles , window ) are not called layers

Comment: perhaps you should read about image manipulation and pattern recognition

Comment: shadow, whatever word you are going to use (wall , sofa , tiles , window) layers , but I hope You understand my question.

Comment: You are actually talking about very vast topic, its not easy and requires lot of image processing. You have to analyze boundaries to detect different objects in the image, and then apply color transformation

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: y it's very vast topic, i need to learn the image manipulation & need to engaged deeply to know how Image actually form starting from it's pixel form.

Comment: because boundary detection requires pattern analysis, filtering, path construction, hough transformation and lots of things to correctly detect any particular object in an image

Comment: You are asking for quite a lot here, it's not a simple peace of code it's actually an entire rendering and analysis engine. Like @shadow mentioned you need to look into image processing patterns and algorithms. You can start [here](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?hl=iw&tab=Tw&q=You%20are%20asking%20for%20quite%20a%20lot%20here%2C#hl=iw&q=Pattern+matcing+in+image&safe=off)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what is stored in an image. You will note that the layers that you might create in a program like PhotoShop can only be saved in PhotoShop's own formats, not in the more common image formats (png, bmp, gif, jpg) that .Net supports. Once you have loaded an image in one of those formats, you will that there is basically just a two dimensional array of colours. There is nothing to separate or link one pixel to its neighbour or indeed any other. So there is absolutely no concept of layer.

You could provide some kind of algorithm that walks your image looking for pixels that are within a tolerance, and in that way defines the set of them, but this will give very poor results. If you aren't sure what I mean then try performing a flood fill on a image in your favourite image editor.

For better results don't use a single image within your application, instead use a set of images, one for each layer, so that you can re-colour the layer you want before putting them back together as you display your composite image.

```
 <Grid>
   <Image Source="Background"/>
   <Image Source="RecolouredImage"/>
   <Image Source="Foreground"/>
 </Grid
```

Of course, this only works if you are in control of the image at development time, and not if it is one the user has loaded at run time.